# How many ways to add to $50$ with $1, 4$ and $6$

Tags: combinatorics

So I get how to find the number of ways of getting a number with $2$ sets of numbers (ex: using $1$s and $2$s to get $10$). But I have no clue where to start to figure out how many ways to get a number using $3$ sets of numbers:

> How many ways can you add to $50$ by using $1$s, $4$s, and $6$s?

Order matters and they count as a way ($1+4$ and $4+1$ is $2$ ways), but all $1$s or all $2$s in different orders count as one way ($1+1$ and $1+1$ is $1$ way).

Is there like a formula that I could use to figure this out? Thanks.

From the comments:

> I tried using brute force with 2 numbers and found a pattern where the next number of ways = number of ways now + previous number of ways. But using brute force with 3 numbers I'm cant seem to find a pattern.

Comment: It would be good if you show us how you do it with sets of 2 numbers. Probably, there is a way to reuse this technique.

Comment: I tried using brute force with 2 numbers and found a pattern where the next number of ways = number of ways now + previous number of ways. But using brute force with 3 numbers I'm cant seem to find a pattern.

Comment: And also I can't find a formula for the 2 ways (I tried), I kinda have to brute force, which I dont want.

Comment: Hey think about the 2-case. it’s divide and conquer to get all partitions, and then it’s combinatorics to get all the partitions counting order. And indeed as @surb said, it generalises (same method applies for 3 numbers), but it can be generalised using generating functions to any arbitrary sized set. I forget the details of the conditions on the set, but surb is right.

Comment: Assume you use 0 ones.  How many ways can you make 50 out of sums of $6,4.$  Assume 1 one, can't do it,  you must have an even number of ones.  2 ones, 4 ones, etc.. find a pattern, justify why the pattern holds.

Comment: So how would a formula look like for the 2-case? Maybe I could use that to figure out the 3-case.

Comment: I can probably use brute force to find 50 out of sums 6 and 4, but I don't want to brute force, I need help coming up with a formula, which I have no clue what it is.

Comment: Do you want ways as, for example, $(6-1)(6+4)$?

Comment: I am stumped, i still cant come up with a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a recurrence.  You can get $50$ by getting $49$ and adding $1$, by getting $46$ and adding $4$, or by getting $44$ and adding $6$.  If $A(n)$ is the number of ways to get $n$ you have $$A(n)=A(n-1)+A(n-4)+A(n-6)\\A(0)=1\\A(n)=0 \quad n \lt 0$$
Unfortunately, the [polynomial that comes out of this,](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E5%3Dx%5E4%2Bx%5E2%2B1) $x^6-x^5-x^2-1,$ cannot be factored easily except for the factor $x+1$ so you are into using numeric approximations for the roots.

Added:  to do it with a calculator you make a column for $n$ with the numbers from $0$ to $50$ and a column for $A(n)$.  Start from the top, putting $A(0)=1$ because there is one way to add to $0$-don't add anything.  Then for each $n$ compute the sum of the lines $1, 4, \text {and} 6$ above.  The result up to $n=20$ is shown below.  For example, you get $A(9)=A(8)+A(5)+A(3)=10+3+1=14$ and keep going.  The image is from Excel, where I could just copy the formula down.

[image]

Comment: Adding also $50$ times $1$?.  Is this valid?

Comment: I don't understand please. ($2^5\gt 2^4+2^2+1$ so the only real root of this polynomial is less than $2$). Regards.

Comment: @Piquito:  Adding $50$ times $1$ is valid.  It falls under the "get $49$ and add $1$" group.  Yes, the only real root is about $1.57$  It is easy to program the recurrence in a spreadsheet.  I get $A(50)=9266038$.  If you could get the roots you could do a formula like Binet's for the Fibonacci numbers.  $A(n)$ would be expressed as a sum of the $n^{th}$ powers of the roots times coefficients to match the initial conditions.

Comment: Thanks you, @Ross. So it is not necessary that $1,4$ and $6$ appeared simultaneously like $(6-1)(6+4)$?

Comment: @Piquito:  I don't understand what you are getting at with the last.  We are adding $1$s, $4$s, and $6$s.  Where do products and subtraction come from?  Your expression evaluates to $50$ but is not part of this problem.

Comment: It was because of my deficient English. I did not understand what the OP wants to.

Comment: I think that's a typo in your reporting of spreadsheet result (I did the same) - should be $92668038$.

Comment: Can confirm $92668038$

Comment: Yes, I dropped a digit on the result.  It is $92668038$

Comment: @Joffan and everyone else


How do you guys get that answer? Idk what numbers to plug in what equations

Comment: @Scooby:  just make a spreadsheet with lines for $-5$ to $50$ for the total.  Put the initial conditions in the next column for lines $-5$ through $0$.  Type the recurrence opposite $1$ and copy down.  The number comes up on line $50$.  Recurrences are easy to do in a spreadsheet as long as you want less than a few thousand lines.

Comment: @RossMillikan Too bad I have to answer this on a piece of paper lol, so if theres a formula that I could use instead of using an excel spreadsheet...then that would be nice

Comment: I think this is an unreasonable problem to give without spreadsheet assistance.  Finding the asymptotic growth rate given a calculator would be reasonable, as it is finding the root of a cubic.  Sums up to $20$ or $25$ would be reasonable with a calculator, but anything above that is just busywork.

Comment: @RossMillikan How would I use your formula:                                    
   A(n) = A(n−1) + A(n−4) + A(n−6) to get A(50) = 92668038? Is it ways to get 49 + ways to get 46 + ways to get 44? But then how would I show it on a piece of paper to get the final answer? (assuming I can use calculator and show results on the paper)

Comment: @RossMillikan on the excel, what do you type exactly into the cell? I tried your formula but got weird numbers, maybe I typed in wrong, thanks.

Comment: @user539262 how do you do this on excel? What do you put in the cell?

Comment: @Joffan how do you do this on excel? What do you put in the cell?

Comment: @Scooby in the A column, starting at row 6, put the numbers $0$ through $50$.  In B6 put 1 because there is one way to make zero.  Then in B7 put =B6+B3+B1 because you can start with one less or four less or six less.  Copy down from B7 to the row with 50 in it.  In my fragment the $98$ comes from $67+21+10$

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks you very much sir!

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:**

Let $f(n)$ be the number of sums that evaluate to $n.$ So $f(5)=3$  because 
$$5=1+1+1+1+1=1+4=4+1$$

The sums that evaluate to $50$ can be splittet into $3$ groups

- the group of sums that starts with $1$
- the group of sums that starts with $4$
- the group of sums that starts with $6$

How can the size of these groups be expressed by $f$?

How can this be used to express $f(50)?$

Finally, calculate $f(50)$ but try to avoid to calculate values you have already calculated otherwise the number of calculations will explode.

Comment: I have no clue where to start, i don't get this and I really need help. Can you show me how to get lets say 20 with 1,4,6. Maybe I could use the technique and find for 50